# provision multiple servers in a single VM using vagrant

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

Can we use vagrant to provision multiple services in a single virtual machine , say tomcat and mysql. but a service should get installed in VM as per user input something like "vagrant up mysql".

I have already been looked in to Mutiple VM deployment using vagrant but here what i want is to have services in same VM based on user input.
Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!!

Comment: The first argument of vagrant up is the machine name.. What is the target of your command?

Comment: @yash, Is possible you use in same Vagrantfile, but in differents machines.

Comment: @GianArb : I just gave the example like we use machine name while doing vagrant up , in the same way or in other way can we do this for services installed in same machine , may be something like setting up variables in vagrantfile and then passing the variable in vagrant up.would be very helpful if u can give pointers on this. thanks in advance..

Comment: I don't understand the use case but in my opinion you can try to install all service in your VM and you can start/stop them with vagrant ssh -c "sudo service mysql stop"

Comment: Hi GianArb , sorry if my question is not clear. Let me try to rephrase the usecase here:

I want to install services say mysql and tomcat in a single VM. Both services will get start doing "vagrant up" but what if I need to start only mysql not tomcat vice versa. Is there a way I can give user input when starting the vagrant machine, so that it only installs one service based on user input. really appreciate any help on this..

Answer (score 0):

Since all those machines are virtual and you sometimes want to have only mysql there, sometimes only tomcat and sometimes both, just use multi-machine:

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/multi-machine/

Then you will be able to start your machine, for example, like this:

```
vagrant up mysql
vagrant up tomcat
vagrant up both
```

You can configure them to have the same IP and never start all of them at once. This should work for you.